# SQL Pivot trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have data which looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
|  Type  |          Description          | Issuer Code | Nominal | book_value  | profit_or_loss | market_value |  exposure   | average_cost | market_price | unrealised_gain |
+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Issuer | BHP Billiton Plc              | BIL         |    1880 | 56073577.75 | NULL           | 55588623.09  | 55588623.09 | 265.486067   | 263.19       | -484954.66      |
| Issuer | Investec Limited              | INL         |    5300 | 14000040642 | NULL           | 28468872315  | 28468872315 | 57.536692    | 117          | 14468831673     |
| Issuer | Topi 40 Futures 15 March 2010 | ALSIH1      |       4 | NULL        | NULL           | NULL         | NULL        | NULL         | NULL         | NULL            |
+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
Type = Issuer
Description = BHP Billiton Plc
Issuer Code = BIL   
Nominal = 1880  
book_value = 56073577.75    
profit_or_loss = NULL   
market_value = 55588623.09  
exposure = 55588623.09  
average_cost = 265.486067000000 
market_price = 263.190000000000 
unrealised_gain = -484954.66


Type = Issuer
Description = Investec Limited
Issuer Code = INL   
Nominal = 5300  
book_value = 14000040641.84
profit_or_loss = NULL   
market_value = 28468872315.00   
exposure = 28468872315.00   
average_cost = 57.536692000000  
market_price = 117.000000000000 
unrealised_gain = 14468831673.16
```

I tried using `PIVOT`, but i have absolutely no idea how to achieve this. Any links or tutorials would be great.

Here is my attempt at the SQL (Not that it helps because i didnt know what I was doing. hehe)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT tb.* INTO #TmpFDH FROM 
(
    SELECT
          instrument_id
         ,date_value
         ,book_value
         ,profit_or_loss
         ,market_value
         ,exposure
         ,average_cost
         ,market_price
         ,unrealised_gain
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY fdh.instrument_id order by d.date_value DESC) as rn
    FROM dw.Fact_Daily_Holding fdh
    JOIN dw.dim_date d 
        ON fdh.holding_date_id = d.date_id
    WHERE convert(date,date_value) = convert(date,GETDATE()-1)
    ) tb
WHERE tb.rn = 1



SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.instrument_id) 
            FROM #TmpFDH c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Type, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                    SELECT
                         i.instrument_id
                        ,rp.related_party_type AS [Type]--TYPE?
                        ,rp.related_party_name AS [Description]--DESCRIPTION?
                        ,rp.related_party_code AS [Issuer Code]--ISSUER CODE?
                        ,ISNULL(fo.traded_nominal,0) AS [Nominal]
                        ,fdh.book_value
                        ,fdh.profit_or_loss
                        ,fdh.market_value
                        ,fdh.exposure
                        ,fdh.average_cost
                        ,fdh.market_price
                        ,fdh.unrealised_gain
                    FROM dw.Dim_Instrument i
                    JOIN dw.Dim_Related_Party rp 
                        ON i.instrument_code = rp.related_party_code
                    LEFT JOIN dw.Fact_Order fo
                        ON i.instrument_id = fo.instrument_id
                    LEFT JOIN #TmpFDH fdh
                        ON i.instrument_id = fdh.instrument_id
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(book_value)
                for instrument_id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table #TmpFDH
```

Comment: Your desired output isn't really organized as a grid that would be returned by SQL.   Is it one column or two?   If you're using a front end app, why not format your current results in the front end?

Comment: @TabAlleman - Wont be using a front end app, I planned on emailing the returned results as a text file from SQL. Thank you though.

Comment: What do you mean "Get it to look like this"?  The values in the columns appear to have different types.  A naive reading of your desired format would have two columns.  But, you can't really store multiple types in a single column.

Comment: Seems you want to get something similar to xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I agree with the comment that there may be a better solution in xml so that also may be an option
2. My condolences that many of your columns are reserved words.
3. What you may be looking for is an `UNPIVOT` like below (given the column names in your example):

   `SELECT *
   FROM mytable
   UNPIVOT (
       value 
       FOR label IN ([Type], [Description], [Issuer Code], [Nominal], [book_value],
        [profit_or_loss], [market_value], [exposure], [average_cost], [market_price], [unrealised_gain])
   ) AS unpivot`

Comment: this is cool - Thanks SQLHound! anyway I can have the value on the other side of the label?